# Undefined reference to `cvCreateBGCodeBookModel'

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm getting following the error message when compiling C++ Code.

```
$g++ basic100.cpp -o test -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
/tmp/ccWqj7E2.o: In function `main':
basic100.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `cvCreateBGCodeBookModel'
basic100.cpp:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to `cvBGCodeBookUpdate'
basic100.cpp:(.text+0x31d): undefined reference to `cvBGCodeBookClearStale'
basic100.cpp:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to `cvBGCodeBookDiff'
basic100.cpp:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `cvSegmentFGMask'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The Code worked fine in my friend's laptop.
My system is 32bit Linux Mint while they have 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Compilation command used in my friend's laptop
$ g++ -o fff basic100.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

This is how I used cvCreateBGCodeBoolModel()

```
(model definition :CvBGCodeBookModel* model = 0;//outside main())

    model = cvCreateBGCodeBookModel();
```

Comment: Have you googled anything?

Comment: Looks like you're missing one of the libraries included by `pkg-config --cflags`. Check on your friend's machine what libraries `pkg-config` lists.

Comment: Thanks to molbdnilo,
Trying to figure out the problem with cflags,
I finally landed up in error in ffmpeg .
But Finally I reinstalled system with ubuntu 14.04,
And things work fine now.
I also feel that my code (Background subtraction) doesn't work with Opencv 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the command

```
grep cvCreateBGCodeBookModel /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_*.so
```

I get the result

```
Binary file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so matches
```

So I assume you're missing the `-lopencv_legacy` flag in the compilation. But I have a 64 bit system.

Can you check and see if that works?

Comment: Sorry, working on the same issue for long I was tiered and installed ubuntu 14.04, now things work fine.
So I can't check it any more.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you lack some of the header files.try making the codebook structure yourself .with opencv 3.0 your code wont work since there you have to use the BackgrundSubtractorMOG class